# Stripping MediaWiki markup from text

Tags: c#, mediawiki, text-processing, strip-tags

If there a way to strip away ALL MediaWiki markup "code" from a text using C#?

For example, I have the following text:

```
<h2><span class="editsection">[<a href="/w/index.php?title=Roger_Zelazny&amp;action=edit&amp;section=1" title="Edit section: Biography">edit</a>]</span> <span class="mw-headline" id="Biography">Biography</span></h2>
<p>Roger Zelazny was born in <a href="/wiki/Euclid,_Ohio" title="Euclid, Ohio">Euclid, Ohio</a>, the only child of Polish immigrant Joseph Frank Zelazny and <a href="/wiki/Irish-American" title="Irish-American" class="mw-redirect">Irish-American</a> Josephine Flora Sweet. In high school, he became the editor of the school newspaper and joined the Creative Writing Club.<sup id="cite_ref-Roger_Zelazny_2009_0-0" class="reference">
<a href="#cite_note-Roger_Zelazny_2009-0"><span>[</span>1<span>]</span></a></sup> In the fall of 1955, he began attending <a href="/wiki/Case_Western_Reserve_University" title="Case Western Reserve University">Western Reserve University</a> and graduated with a B.A. in English in 1959.<sup id="cite_ref-Roger_Zelazny_2009_0-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Roger_Zelazny_2009-0"><span>[</span>1<span>]</span></a></sup> He was accepted to <a href="/wiki/Columbia_University" title="Columbia University">Columbia University</a> in New York and specialized in Elizabethan and Jacobean drama, graduating with an M.A. in 1962.<sup id="cite_ref-Roger_Zelazny_2009_0-2" class="reference">
<a href="#cite_note-Roger_Zelazny_2009-0"><span>[</span>1<span>]</span></a></sup> His M.A. thesis was entitled <i>Two traditions and <a href="/wiki/Cyril_Tourneur" title="Cyril Tourneur">Cyril Tourneur</a>: an examination of morality and humor comedy conventions in</i> <a href="/wiki/The_Revenger%27s_Tragedy" title="The Revenger's Tragedy">The Revenger's Tragedy</a>. Between 1962 and 1969 he worked for the U.S. <a href="/wiki/Social_Security_Administration" title="Social Security Administration">Social Security Administration</a> in <a href="/wiki/Cleveland,_Ohio" title="Cleveland, Ohio" class="mw-redirect">Cleveland, Ohio</a> and then in <a href="/wiki/Baltimore,_Maryland" title="Baltimore, Maryland" class="mw-redirect">Baltimore, Maryland</a> spending his evenings writing science fiction.<sup id="cite_ref-Roger_Zelazny_2009_0-3" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Roger_Zelazny_2009-0"><span>[</span>1<span>]</span></a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-AndCall_1-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-AndCall-1"><span>[</span>2<span>]</span></a></sup> 
He deliberately progressed from short-shorts to novelettes to novellas and finally to novel-length works by 1965.<sup id="cite_ref-Roger_Zelazny_2009_0-4" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Roger_Zelazny_2009-0"><span>[</span>1<span>]</span></a></sup> On May 1, 1969, he quit to become a full-time writer, and thereafter concentrated on writing novels in order to maintain his income.<sup id="cite_ref-AndCall_1-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-AndCall-1"><span>[</span>2<span>]</span></a></sup>
During this period, he was an active and vocal member of the Baltimore Science Fiction Society, whose members included writers <a href="/wiki/Jack_Chalker" title="Jack Chalker" class="mw-redirect">Jack Chalker</a> and <a href="/wiki/Joe_Haldeman" title="Joe Haldeman">Joe</a> and <a href="/wiki/Jack_Haldeman" title="Jack Haldeman" class="mw-redirect">Jack Haldeman</a> among others.</p>
```

Which is represented bt the following Html:

> ### [[edit](/w/index.php?title=Roger_Zelazny&action=edit&section=1)] Biography
>
> Roger Zelazny was born in [Euclid, Ohio](/wiki/Euclid,_Ohio), the only child of Polish immigrant Joseph Frank Zelazny and Irish-American Josephine Flora Sweet. In high school, he became the editor of the school newspaper and joined the Creative Writing Club.
>   [1] In the fall of 1955, he began attending [Western Reserve University](/wiki/Case_Western_Reserve_University) and graduated with a B.A. in English in 1959.[1] He was accepted to [Columbia University](/wiki/Columbia_University) in New York and specialized in Elizabethan and Jacobean drama, graduating with an M.A. in 1962.
>   [1] His M.A. thesis was entitled *Two traditions and [Cyril Tourneur](/wiki/Cyril_Tourneur): an examination of morality and humor comedy conventions in* [The Revenger's Tragedy](/wiki/The_Revenger%27s_Tragedy). Between 1962 and 1969 he worked for the U.S. [Social Security Administration](/wiki/Social_Security_Administration) in Cleveland, Ohio and then in Baltimore, Maryland spending his evenings writing science fiction.[1][2] 
>   He deliberately progressed from short-shorts to novelettes to novellas and finally to novel-length works by 1965.[1] On May 1, 1969, he quit to become a full-time writer, and thereafter concentrated on writing novels in order to maintain his income.[2]
>   During this period, he was an active and vocal member of the Baltimore Science Fiction Society, whose members included writers Jack Chalker and [Joe](/wiki/Joe_Haldeman) and Jack Haldeman among others.

I'm looking for a way to strip *not only* the HTML tags, but also things like references, wiki "links", etc. - I'd like to remove every formatting and "processing" done by Wikipedia, and keep only the text...

Comment: Why not start with the source?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML will not get you far, as it will be near-impossible to tell what's "content" and what is not.  What you need is a MediaWiki markup parser, but while there are dozens, [the canonical list at mediawiki.org](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) does not (at time of writing) seem to have any for C#.

If you end up calling out to any external library, [mwlib](http://pediapress.com/code/) is probably the most mature of the bunch.